# Is there a directory of optimisation handbooks for D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization

On the eve of 5th edition, there has been a *great deal* of bit rot since the dark days of 2003-2004. Forums have lived and died, and many of the trivial searches on google show ancient threads.

Therefore, is there a list or resource for the most up to date, well formatted (i.e., updated since the "Gleemax" days) and comprehensive optimisation handbooks for 3.5?

Comment: I also asked this question because it'll be useful to link people to it.

Comment: I voted to reopen. These character optimization handbooks, for whatever reason, seem to be collected on a single forum.

Answer (score 5):

**[Minmaxboards Handbook Index](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=399.0)** is the most updated and complete.  It includes some old 339 content and some gitp content.

**[Minmaxboards Pathfinder Handbook Index](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1932.0)** is where their PF content is collated.

Giantitp nuked all it's sticky threads, so their indexes are mostly gone.

All the 339 stuff is either ported or gone, very few handbooks or optimization resources remain through the board churn and numerous content nukes.

Minmaxboards is the most-used and only updated Handbook/Resource Index i've been able to find.

Comment: The links seem to be dead, could you provide new ones? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Min/Max <strike>Boards'</strike> Forum's [Handbook Index](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=399.0) has a seemingly exhaustive and up-to-date collection of optimization handbooks, although you may have to sift through to separate the 3.5 content from Pathfinder.